# Jmeter and Oracle Connections - JDBC Request

Tags: oracle, jmeter-5.0

When I try to use the JDBC Connector I'm getting this error when I go to try and send a SQL.

I'm getting a weird error that I don't understand when trying to connect a JDBC request to an Oracle DB.

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract isValid(I)Z of interface java.sql.Connection.
>       at or

What's going on here? #jmeter

Comment: Show your JDBC configuration

Answer (score 0):

JDBC driver might be outdated.  Does ojdbc8.jar exist in your Jmeter/lib directory?

If not, try downloading it to that directory from the link below. Then, re-start Jmeter and reattempt the connection.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/jdbc-ucp-183-5013470.html

Comment: This file is jdbc-oracle.jar,

Answer (score 0):

You should add `ojdbc7.jar` to your Test Plan

You can click on Browse and add it, Save Test Plan and restart JMeter